# How to deploy streamlit python app on firebase hosting?

Tags: firebase, machine-learning, firebase-hosting, streamlit

I am aiming to deploy a simple web-app written with Streamlit, e.g.

```
app.py
```

-

```
import streamlit as st
st.title('Hello World!')
```

I can run this on my local machine by running streamlit run app.py in my command line.

However, I'm not sure how  to deploy it on firebase hosting.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually I don't know if there's a way to deploy it using firebase hosting as it is mainly for static content and also right now there isn’t a way to directly deploy your app through Streamlit, but we are working on our “For Teams” offering which is currently in the development phase. 
If you’d like to sign-up and hear about it when more information becomes available [here](https://streamlit.io/forteams/) is the link.

In the meantime, the community has come up with some amazing ways to deploy Streamlit apps . Here are a few forum discussions:

- [Deploying on Azure](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-deploy-streamlit-on-azure/700/2)
- [Deploying on Glitch](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/development-and-deployment-using-glitch/604)
- [Deploying on Heroku](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/hosting-streamlit-on-heroku/132/12)

A few additional resources would be this article written on Medium:

- [Deploying with AWS EC2 3](https://medium.com/@pokepim/deploying-streamlit-app-to-ec2-instance-7a7edeffbb54)

And a couple of YouTube video tutorials by JCharis:

- [How to deploy Streamlit apps [using Heroku]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skpiLtEN3yk&feature=youtu.be)
- [How to deploy Streamlit apps on AWS Ec2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJTa625q85o&feature=youtu.be)

Hopefully this helps and feel free to let me know if you have any questions! Also any feedback you have on the type of deployment and sharing you would like would be useful as we shape the For Teams product.